# How can I Normalized a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalization

I use below code for normalizing my matrix; cause of amplitude of my data is very different in each column than other column, so my answers aren't between 0 and 1.

```
A = rand(m,n)
normA = max(A) - min(A);               
normA = repmat(normA, [length(a) 1]);  

normalizedA = A./normA;
```

a part of my original data are:

```
32512035.2100000    5401399.57000000    346.880000000000
32512044.0300000    5401399.54000000    346.850000000000
32512046.8900000    5401399.55000000    346.780000000000
32512049.7800000    5401399.53000000    346.860000000000
32512052.6900000    5401399.53000000    346.700000000000
32512054.0300000    5401399.53000000    346.780000000000
32512055.6900000    5401399.57000000    346.810000000000
32512063.1200000    5401399.54000000    347.800000000000
32512074.2300000    5401399.55000000    346.440000000000
32512093.1200000    5401399.54000000    346.660000000000
```

and the normalized of them are:

```
341584.736395270    39652.0303186782    6.02013189864630
341584.829061797    39652.0300984462    6.01961124609511
341584.859110126    39652.0301718569    6.01839639014231
341584.889473648    39652.0300250355    6.01978479694551
341584.920047298    39652.0300250355    6.01700798333912
341584.934125886    39652.0300250355    6.01839639014231
341584.951566525    39652.0303186782    6.01891704269351
341585.029629143    39652.0300984462    6.03609857688303
341585.146355346    39652.0301718569    6.01249566122874
341585.344821410    39652.0300984462    6.01631377993752
```

Do I have to normalized any column separately?

Comment: Of course this doesn't work; if all the values were between 5 and 6, for example, then you'd be dividing everything by 1.

Comment: However, you shouldn't need to do any of this.  `rand` already gives you values between 0 and 1...

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
max_value = max(A(:));
min_value = min(A(:));
normalizedA = (A - min_value)/(max_value - min_value);
```