# How to normalize a large data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, normalization

I am new in matlab and I have a file contains 657 columns and 97 rows and I want to normalize these data set between 0 and 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Normalize a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041572/how-can-i-normalized-a-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

The same way you can do in any code or calculation, being `A` you matrix, divide  by the maximum of `A`:

As noted by @AnderBiguri, If you data is not starting from zero, you need to do some math:

```
A_normalized= (A-min(A(:)))/(max(A(:))-min(A(:)))
```

If is starting from zero:

```
A_normalized=A/max(A(:))
```

Note that `A(:)` get all the numbers, no need to the the max in each column.
If this is not what you want, give it some comments.

Comment: This is only valid if the original data has 0 as minimum

Comment: @AnderBiguri Completely forgot that possibility! Thanks for noticing, already adjusted!